# Laravel 5.1 - Routes giving NotFoundHttpException and redirects to 404 Error

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am having a bewildering problem. I think that code in correct.
When I am trying to access to get route on browser redirects to 404 Error Page, that's mean is a route is not found. Once I MOVED a route to above or down, and try again will working.

But now I have two routes, If I've moved one of these routes to above another one or vice versa, just one of them will work.

I need explanation and Solution please..

This is routes.php file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Information AR
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
View::share('application_name_ar', config('systemconfig.application_name_ar'));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
 */

Route::get('/', [function () {
    return redirect()->route('en.welcome');
},
]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Dashboard Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::get('dashboard/login', ['as' => 'dashboard.login', function () {
        return view('dashboard.login');
    }]);
});
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard/manage', ['as' => 'dashboard.manage.index', function () {
        return view('dashboard.manage.index');
    },
    ]);

    //Request management
    Route::controller('dashboard/manage', 'System\RequestManageController', [
        'postUpdateRequestStatus' => 'dashboard.manage.requests.status.update',
        'getRequest'              => 'dashboard.manage.requests.show',
        'getPendingRequests'      => 'dashboard.manage.requests.pending',
        'getApprovedRequests'     => 'dashboard.manage.requests.approved',
        'getRejectedRequests'     => 'dashboard.manage.requests.rejected',
    ]);

    //Search management
    Route::controller('dashboard/manage', 'System\SearchController', [
        'postSearchInUsers'    => 'dashboard.manage.search.in.users',
        'postSearchInRequests' => 'dashboard.manage.search.in.requests',
        'getReindexAll'        => 'dashboard.manage.search.reindex',
        'getSearch'            => 'dashboard.manage.search',
    ]);

    Route::get('dashboard', ['as' => 'dashboard.start', function () {
        return view('dashboard.start');
    },
    ]);

});

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Arabic Site Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
Route::get('ar', ['as' => 'ar.welcome', function () {
    return view('ar.welcome');
},
]);

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| English Site Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

Route::get('en', ['as' => 'en.welcome', function () {
    return view('en.welcome');
},
]);

/*
|
| Homes Routes
|
 */
Route::get('en/home', ['as' => 'en.home', function () {
    return view('en.home.index');
},
]);

Route::get('en/home/patents-registration', ['as' => 'en.home.patents', function () {
    return view('en.home.patent');
},
]);

Route::get('en/home/industrial-registration', ['as' => 'en.home.industrial-registration', function () {
    return view('en.home.industrial-registration');
},
]);

Route::get('en/home/computer-software-registration', ['as' => 'en.home.computersoftware-registration', function () {
    return view('en.home.computersoftware-registration');
},
]);

// just for users
Route::group(['middleware' => 'signedin'], function () {

    // just for users completed profile
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'informationcompleted'], function () {

        //******************************\\
        //******************************\\
        //  Payment routes
        //******************************\\
        //******************************\\
        Route::get('en/home/{regRequest}/checkout', ['as' => 'en.home.checkout', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@checkout']);

        Route::get('en/home/registration/done', ['uses' => 'PaymentController@paypalDone']);

        Route::get('en/home/registration/failed', [function () {
            return "It has failed";
        },
        ]);

        Route::post('en/home/checkout/pay/credit-card', ['as' => 'en.home.pay.credit.card', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeCreditCard']);

        Route::post('en/home/checkout/pay/paypal', ['as' => 'en.home.pay.paypal', 'uses' => 'PaymentController@storePaypal']);

        Route::post('en/home/patents/store-request', ['as' => 'en.home.patents.request.store', 'uses' => 'RegisterRequestsController@storePatent']);
        Route::get('en/home/patents-registration/download-application', ['as' => 'en.home.patents.app.pdf', function () {
            $pathToFile = storage_path('app/system/docs/patent_app.pdf');
            $name       = "Patents Application.pdf";
            return response()->download($pathToFile, $name);
        },
        ]);

        Route::post('en/home/industrial-registration/store-request', ['as' => 'en.home.industrial.request.store', 'uses' => 'RegisterRequestsController@storeIndustrial']);
        Route::get('en/home/industrial-registration/download-application', ['as' => 'en.home.industrial.app.pdf', function () {
            $pathToFile = storage_path('app/system/docs/model_app.pdf');
            $name       = "Industrial Application.pdf";
            return response()->download($pathToFile, $name);
        },
        ]);

        Route::post('en/home/computer-software-registration/store-request', ['as' => 'en.home.cs.request.store', 'uses' => 'RegisterRequestsController@storeCS']);
        Route::get('en/home/computer-software-registration/download-application', ['as' => 'en.home.cs.app.pdf', function () {
            $pathToFile = storage_path('app/system/docs/cs_app.pdf');
            $name       = "Software Patent Application.pdf";
            return response()->download($pathToFile, $name);
        },
        ]);
    });

    // end just for users completed profile

    // messages routes
    Route::get('en/my-account/messages/download-attachment-file', ['as' => 'en.home.messages.download', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@downloadAttachmentFile']);
    Route::post('en/my-account/messages/markasread/{id}', ['as' => 'en.home.messages.markasread', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@markAsRead']);
    Route::post('en/my-account/messages/markasunread/{id}', ['as' => 'en.home.messages.markasunread', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@markAsUnread']);
    Route::resource('en/my-account/messages', 'MessagesController');

    /*
    |
    | Account Routes
    |
     */
    Route::get('en/my-account/{code}/request', ['as' => 'en.account.request.show', function ($code) {
        if (xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('code', $code)->first() == null) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Request code is not correct.');
            return Redirect::back();
        }
        $request = xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('code', $code)->first();

        // show messages
        try {
            $thread = Cmgmyr\Messenger\Models\Thread::findOrFail($request->thread_id);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            Session::flash('error_message', 'The thread with ID: ' . $id . ' was not found.');
            return redirect('messages');
        }
        // show current user in list if not a current participant
        $users  = Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser::whereNotIn('id', $thread->participantsUserIds())->get();
        $userId = Sentinel::getUser();
        $thread->markAsRead($userId);

        return view('en.account.request-show', ['request' => $request, 'thread' => $thread, 'users' => $users]);
    }]);
    Route::get('en/my-account/request/{code}/cancel', ['as' => 'en.account.request.cancel', function ($code) {

        if (xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('code', $code)->first() == null) {
            Session::flash('error', 'Request code is not correct.');
            return Redirect::back();
        }
        $regRequest = xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('code', $code)->first();

        if ($regRequest->is_paid) {
            Session::flash('error', 'You can\'t cancel this request.');
            return Redirect::back();
        } else {
            xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('code', $code)->delete();
            Session::flash('success', 'Your Request has been Canceled.');
            return redirect()->route('en.account');
        }
    },
    ]);
    Route::get('en/my-account/requests', ['as' => 'en.account.requests', function () {
        $requests_approved = xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('is_approved', 1)->get();
        $requests_pending  = xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('is_approved', null)->where('is_paid', 1)->get();
        $requests_rejected = xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('is_approved', 0)->get();
        $requests_not_paid = xProject\RegistrationRequest::where('is_paid', 0)->get();
        return view('en.account.requests', ['requests_approved' => $requests_approved, 'requests_pending' => $requests_pending, 'requests_rejected' => $requests_rejected, 'requests_not_paid' => $requests_not_paid]);
    },
    ]);
    Route::get('en/my-account/profile', ['as' => 'en.account.profile', function () {
        return view('en.account.profile');
    },
    ]);
    Route::get('en/my-account', ['as' => 'en.account', function () {
        return view('en.account.index');
    },
    ]);

    Route::controller('en/my-account', 'MyAccountController', ['postUpdateInformation' => 'en.account.updateinformation', 'postUpdatePassword' => 'en.account.updatepassword', 'postUpdatePP' => 'en.account.updatepp', 'postUpdateIdProof' => 'en.account.updateid']);
});

// end just for users

/*
|
| Auth Routes
|
 */
Route::get('en/faq', ['as' => 'en.faq', function () {
    return view('en.faq');
},
]);
Route::get('en/contact-us', ['as' => 'en.contact-us', function () {
    return view('en.contact-us');
},
]);
Route::post('en/contact-us/post', ['as' => 'en.contact-us.post', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@contactMessageStore']);
Route::get('en/about-us', ['as' => 'en.about-us', function () {
    return view('en.about-us');
},
]);
Route::get('en/logout', ['as' => 'get.logout', function () {
    Sentinel::logout(null, true);
    return Redirect::route('en.welcome');
},
]);

Route::group(['middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
    Route::get('en/signup', ['as' => 'en.signup', function () {
        return view('en.signup');
    },
    ]);

    Route::get('en/verify', ['as' => 'en.verification', function () {
        return view('en.verification');
    },
    ]);

    Route::get('en/login', ['as' => 'en.login', function () {
        return view('en.login');
    },
    ]);

    Route::get('en/ResetPassword', ['as' => 'en.resetpassword', function () {
        return view('en.resetpassword');
    },
    ]);

    Route::controller('auth', 'Auth\AuthController', ['postSignup' => 'post.signup', 'postLogin' => 'post.login', 'postVerification' => 'post.verification', 'postResend' => 'post.resend', 'postResetpassword' => 'post.resetpassword']);
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English :/

Comment: are you talking about these Routes ??  Route::controller('dashboard/manage'.......

Comment: Are you calling the route using get method if not then only it will throw that error

Comment: @vikram yes I am call get method

Comment: @Qazi Any Solutions ?

Comment: what my understanding is, instead of using Route::controller('dashboard/manage',....... you should use Route::group().. I think that will make more sense, follow this URL https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#implicit-controllers